# Read MP3 rating using TagLib

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, id3

I have a music application which reads ID3 tags with `TagLib` library. It's working good on artist, title, album, year...

But I cannot read ratings. I've tried this:

```
TagLib.File track = TagLib.File.Create(name);
TagLib.Tag tag123 = track.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2);
var usr = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame frame = TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame.Get(
                                         (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tag123, usr, true);
```

but `frame.PlayCount` and `frame.Rating` are always `0`

Does anyone have an idea why my code does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usr = "Windows Media Player 9 Series"

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this problem myself, and the marked answer didn't solve it for me. Frankly, it's not even much of an answer/solution - just a lucky guess that seems to have worked out for OP.

According to the ID3v2(3) specification, the purpose of the Popularimeter/POPM field is the following...

> The purpose of this frame is to specify how good an audio file is. Many interesting applications could be found to this frame such as a playlist that features better audiofiles more often than others or it could be used to profile a person's taste and find other 'good' files by comparing people's profiles. The frame is very simple. It contains the email address to the user, one rating byte and a four byte play counter, intended to be increased with one for every time the file is played. The email is a terminated string. The rating is 1-255 where 1 is worst and 255 is best. 0 is unknown. If no personal counter is wanted it may be omitted. When the counter reaches all one's, one byte is inserted in front of the counter thus making the counter eight bits bigger in the same away as the play counter ("PCNT"). There may be more than one "POPM" frame in each tag, but only one with the same email address.

[Source](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Popularimeter)

Take note of that last sentence; there may be multiple POPM fields - but only one for each email address. From my understanding, TagLib returns empty ratings if you don't provide an actually existing email (user) value. In this case, it seems like the lucky guess of *usr = "Windows Media Player 9 Series"* seemed to work out because Windows Media Player likely was the author of OP's rating.

The solution for me, who uses MediaMonkey, was to figure out what email address value is used by that application - which is "no@email". Once I provided that value as an argument, I could retrieve all my ratings.